# Should cyaphide create similar chemical compounds as cyanide?

Tags: organophosphorus-compounds

The *cyaphide* anion $\ce{(CP)-}$ should be chemically similar to its nitrogen analogue cyanide. $\ce{(CN-})$ But unlike it's counterpart it readily polymerizes  so it has only been found in outer space naturally. However, it should form compounds that should be the same  like cyanides.For example sodium cyanide ($\ce{NaCN}$),would be called "sodium cyaphide" ($\ce{NaCP}$) and hydrogen cyanide ($\ce{HCN}$) would be called hydrogen cyaphide or as it's called *methylidynephosphane* ($\ce{HCP}$) and the anions: phosphaethynolate (*cyaphate*) ($\ce{PCO-}$) and *thio*phosphaethyonlate (*thiocyaphate*), ($\ce{PCS-}$) and also potentially the *cyaphogen* ($\ce{P2C2}$) have been observed but as far as I know the only reliable info I found on cyaphides were on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyaphide) and they were very short as well. Which source on information do I go with?

More information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methylidynephosphane

Comment: Also I'm basing the nomenclature from the PCO-/PCS- anions from the cyanate and thiocyanate anions

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyaphide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Methylidynephosphane or phosphaethyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methylidynephosphane) is known and it has been achieved in 1961 by Thurman Gier. He passed phosphine gas at low pressure over an electric arc produced between two carbon electrodes. Condensation of the gaseous products in a –196 °C (–321 °F) trap revealed that the reaction had produced phosphaethyne along with acetylene and ethylene.

$$\ce{PH3 ->[electric arc][carbon electrodes] HCP + H2C=CH2 + HC#CH}$$

The ions $\ce{PCO-}$ and $\ce{PCS-}$ are also known. From the abstract of this paper<sup>1</sup>:

> **A range of λ3-phosphaalkynes $\ce{P⋮C−R}$ $\ce{(R = F, Cl, O-, OLi, OH,}$
> $\ce{OSiMe3, S-}$, $\ce{SLi}$, $\ce{SH, Me,}$ $\ce{SiMe3, H)}$ has been geometry-optimized at the HF, MP2, and CCSD(T) level of theory**. Vibrational frequencies as well as 31P and 13C NMR chemical shifts were calculated and compared to experimental values of the large variety of λ3-phosphaalkynes prepared over several years via differing synthetic routes. With a few obvious exceptions, a good agreement of calculated and experimental parameters was found. This also opens up the possibility to make predictions on
> spectroscopic data of compounds not yet synthesized or fully
> characterized, e.g., $\ce{PCOSiMe3}$ and $\ce{PCSH}$. **The bonding situation
> especially of the negatively charged species $\ce{P⋮C−O-}$ and $\ce{P⋮C−S-}$ was
> studied via NBO analyses to determine the degree of phosphaalkyne and
> heterocumulene contributions to the mesomeric anions.**
> $$\ce{^{-}X-C#P <-> X=C=P- (X=O,S)}$$

Cyaphogen ($\ce{(CP)2}$) has not been synthesized yet. [It is considered a pseudohalogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudohalogen). Structurally, it is formulated as $\ce{P#C-C#P}$.

Currently, no binary cyaphides are known but numerous organometallic cyaphide complexes are known. Some of them are listed in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyaphide).

**Reference**

1. Theoretical Studies of NMR Chemical Shifts and Vibrational Frequencies in λ3-Phosphaalkynes P⋮C−R, Klaus Hübler and Peter Schwerdtfeger, Inorganic Chemistry **1999** 38 (1), 157-164, DOI: [10.1021/ic9811291](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ic9811291)